# 'Installing' Applications, where to put folders?

Tags: filesystem

I've just bought a game (Machinarium) which does not come with a deb file neither is it a ./configure, make etc type of application. I can just run it. Where is the best place to put it so i can create a launcher and keep it out of my home directory?

i.e. I'm basically asking where are applications are installed and should i put this game there.

Thanks!

Comment: I've left it in home as i've had trouble putting it in opt, the flash files weren't read so I've left it in home at the moment which works with a custom launcher located here "http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/2058/creating-a-launcher-for-mechinarium" Please give props to the user if it helps you out!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Usually you would select `/opt` or `/usr/local` as installation path.

You need to use `sudo` if you want to copy anything into those directories.

Comment: Hmmm i seem to be having trouble copying. In the command line i type 
"cp -r /home/will/Machinarium /opt"
and i get this error:
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory `/opt/Machinarium' with directory `/home/will/Machinarium'

Comment: You would declare the installation path to `./configure`

Comment: I would go with `/opt`

Comment: @txwikinger. This is a windows-like setup for a closed source game. So no ./configure for him.

Comment: What kind of games is that? Running under wine?

Comment: No its a flash game, native to linux, the executable is basically just a click and run type thing, it needs to read some folders with .swf files in the same directory

Comment: I almost exclusively recommend `/opt` - that's pretty much what `/opt` is there for.

Comment: According to the File Hierarchy Standard (FHS) both are possible. `/opt` was always the option in System V based Unix systems to install [additional software](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES). However, system administrators often use /usr/local/ instead since it parallels the /usr directory but protects the content of being [overwritten by updates](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY). So both places are really the same, the redundancy exists because of historical reasons.

Comment: I use `/usr/local/` for more "unixy" applications (those that are split in the usual subdirs `bin/`, `lib/`, etc.), and use `/opt/` for more exotic stuff, e.g. Eclipse.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the fact that you have paid money for it, might be a good idea keeping it close to other documents that you will definitely take care of, that is, in the home directory.

`~/bin` is not widely known location but it is added in the PATH by bash so it looks pretty standard to me.

Comment: Well, I keep a backup on an external HD and i have the emails with the DL links archived so i think it will be fine putting it somewhere else than home, its clogged enough as it is! thanks for the help