# How can I make /etc/rc.local run on startup?

Tags: startup, scripts

I have a script I would like to run when my system starts and have put it in `/etc/rc.local`, but it doesn't work. How can I enable it to run on startup?

Comment: Where is the xsetwacom command? /etc/rc.local is executed with a very simple PATH at startup. It probably differs from the PATH you have logged in at the terminal. In the terminal, type: type -p xsetwacom then replace the "xsetwacom" command in /etc/rc.local with the full path as returned by the "type -p". Do you have to do any manual initializations before xsetwacom works for you?

Comment: Using **systemd** as startup manager  make sure the rc.local compatibility is running: `systemctl status rc-local.service`

Comment: waltinator's comment was my problem.  Because of the minimal path, it didn't know how to run the scripts I wanted to be run.  The path loaded on my Ubuntu 14.04 system at the time of runninig /etc/rc.local was the following: /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin... you could check yours by putting `echo $PATH > /home/rc_local_path` into your /etc/rc.local and then checking the file after it's been run on startup.

Comment: Keep in mind that if your script needs to **run continuously** [you have to start it as a daemon](http://askubuntu.com/a/191715/323990) in the `rc.local` file!

Comment: Use `sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service` to ensure that `/etc/rc.local `is executed during the server startup

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Can you run your script manually; if not, it's a problem with that script, otherwise look more at `rc.local`. If that script needs to run as `root`,  `sudo` must be used to manually run it.

- Ensure `/etc/rc.local`, and the script it call, is executable:

  ```bsh
  ls -l /etc/rc.local
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 419 2010-08-27 11:26 /etc/rc.local
  ```
- Ensure `rc.local` has a shebang line, which is the default:

  ```bsh
  head -n1 /etc/rc.local
    #!/bin/sh -e
  ```

Comment: Yes, I can run the script manually. How can I make sure /etc/rc.local is executable? What do I have to type? Is it "$ ls -l /etc/rc.local
-rwxr-xr-x 1"? Thanks!

Comment: @pedroo: I've copied exactly what I *see* in my terminal (so you see the prompt, input, and output all above).  The command is "ls -l /etc/rc.local" and if it's executable, it will have those Xs in the output.

Comment: I've tried the "ls -l /etc/rc.local" and it is executable, but I cannot make it run on startup... Any idea?

Comment: @pedroo: What does this script do? Does it write to any log files that you need to check? (I think it's time to update the question with more details.)

Comment: It's a xsetwacom command. When I run it in terminal, it works. But it doesn't run automatically when booting...

Comment: @pedroo: That needs the X server running, which doesn't happen when rc.local executes.  Running it from rc.local will just make it exit without doing anything (though I hope it puts a message in syslog or elsewhere).  You need to put the xsetwacom commands in ~/.xinitrc or /etc/X/xinit/xinitrc instead.

Comment: The commands in .xinitrc didn't work too. But I've managed to get it to work by putting the 'rc.local' on StartUp Applications. Problem Solved! Thanks for your input!

Comment: @pedroo: Do *not* put rc.local on Startup Applications.  Instead put the xsetwacom command you want to run there, or create a new script with multiple commands and call it from Startup Applications.

Comment: I'm kind of a newbie to linux. How do I create a new script with multiple commands? Why can't I put rc.local on Startup Applications? Thanks.

Comment: @pedroo: Because rc.local contains commands intended to run at a different time.  Create a new file, you can put it in [~/bin](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9848/what-are-path-and-bin-how-can-i-have-personal-scripts), mark it executable (chmod or properties in Nautilus), make the first line "#!/bin/bash", then put your commands on later lines.

Comment: It works. Nice!

Answer (score 62):

In my case, none of the instructions were a perfect solution, so try this detailed one:

1. Save all executing code in a separate text file with an arbitrary name, such as `foo.sh`
2. Add `#!/bin/sh` as the first line in `foo.sh`, executing it via `sudo foo.sh` to check for errors
3. In `/etc/rc.local`, place the full pathname to `foo.sh`, prefaced with `sh`, before `exit 0`:

   ```
   sh '/path/to/your/script/foo.sh'
   ```
4. Verify the first line in `/etc/rc.local` is `#!/bin/sh -e`
5. Ensure `/etc/rc.local` is executable:

   ```
   sudo chown root /etc/rc.local
   sudo chmod 755 /etc/rc.local
   ```
6. Verify everything works fine:

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/rc.local start
   ```
7. Reboot to test

Comment: Step #8 was the key, verifying that the script will run under the startup environment.  In my case I need to give the full path to the command.

Comment: Prefect and step to step greats, it's works on centos but `sudo /etc/rc.local start` first run.

Comment: Thanks - this break down really helped for me and as above step #8 was the key for me too! Without that it woudn't redirect +1 (for reference, node app running on bitnami cloud server using [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) for continuous running).

Comment: Step 8 was a good tip, But i think step 7 might be what fixed mine, I was trying to run the script using cron to open a tunnel but it was failing randomly

Comment: In 6 and 7, you write about /etc/rc.local, but in 8, it's /etc/init.d/rc.local. On my 18.04, I have neither of these, shall I create them? Are you talking about different files or is it a mistake?

Answer (score 43):

On newer Ubuntu versions **`systemd`** is used and `/etc/rc.local` is not loaded always by default.

Check if the Compatibility service is loaded with

```
systemctl status rc-local.service
```

[image: screenshot]

If it contains **active (exited)** your setting seems fine and you could have another error in your `/etc/rc.local` file (this could be a command that fails for example).

Comment: if rc-local.service is not activated,  check this post that explains [How to Enable /etc/rc.local with Systemd](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd)

Answer (score 4):

2 suggestions.

1. Ensure that the target script file is also marked executable.
2. <strike>Is the target script running a **sudo** command? If so you might want to supply the sudo password to it.</strike>

My bad. Just check one then. Thanks for the correction enzotib :)

Comment: `rc.local` is run as root, so no password is necessary.