# No "startup applications" menu in Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: startup, 14.10

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.10 (Unity) and I cannot find any way to manage the startup applications. I have done the usual first to unhide hidden applications (sudo sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop) and then tried typing start, startup etc in dash but no program shows up. I've searched through all applications and can't find it anywhere.

Does anybody have an idea how I can fix this? Is there something that failed to install?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of `gnome-session-properties`?

Comment: No gnome-session-properties, when I try I get "The program 'gnome-session-properties' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-bin". gnome-session-bin is installed but does not contain gnome-session-properties

Comment: Install `gnome-session-properties` with the `apt` command - you can then use `gnome-session-properties` to manage Startup applications* (see also [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/48321/178596)) **Applications that start when you log in* - for ones that start when you boot the computer, [use `rc.local`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9853/how-can-i-make-rc-local-run-on-startup/9880#9880).

Comment: I also installed Ubuntu 14.10 as a fresh install, but I do have the startup application program. Could it be something with your installation?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using ubuntu Gnome and do not seem to have gnome-session-properties. Instead I found you can use the gnome-tweak-tool and there is a section for startup programs in there.

Answer (score 1):

`gnome-session-properties` is not installed with the latest version `gnome-session-bin` package in Ubuntu 14.10. If you check `/usr/bin/` folder, you will see only `gnome-session`, `gnome-session-inhibit`, and `gnome-session-quit`.

A work around is go to:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gnome-session-bin

and download(end of the page) the package as per system architecture. It's a ".deb" file. Instead of installing, unpack the file with the following command:

```
dpkg-deb -x gnome-session-bin_3.9.90-0ubuntu12_amd64.deb ~/Desktop/
```

The extract would be a folder named `usr`. Inside you will see `bin` , `lib`, `share`. Go to `bin` and there you will find `gnome-session-properties`. You can then move/copy the file to `/usr/bin/` of your system or type in terminal (be careful):

```
sudo nautilus
```

and drag the file to `/usr/bin/` folder.

Go to terminal and type `sudo gnome-session-properties` and the startup applications preference window will show up.