# 'ssh -R' won't run in /etc/rc.local

Tags: networking, startup

I wrote the following command in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
ssh -R 32400:192.168.0.100:32400 root@marcin.com -N
```

but it won't start.

Any idea why?

Comment: You can't get an output of commands run in `/etc/rc.local` as they don't run in a terminal. I guess you want to run this in a terminal / tty once logged in right? Do you login using a GUI or using a tty?

Comment: this runs on Raspberry Pi and i want to run it as fast as RPi boots up

Comment: Some clarifications: 1) Does it work if run from command line? 2) Does it ask for a password?

Comment: it works from command line, i have added rsa key to server as user and as root

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the network isn't ready yet, when `rc.local` is executed.

The following code will wait for the network before connecting:

```
(
until ping -nq -c3 W.X.Y.Z; do
   # Waiting for network
   sleep 5
done
ssh -R 32400:192.168.0.100:32400 root@marcin.com -N
)&
```

<sub>`W.X.Y.Z` is an IP address that is reachable and replies to pings. It maybe be the default gateway of your network, the Google DNS (8.8.8.8), etc.</sub>

Code between parenthesis runs in a new shell, and the `&` makes it run in background. It won't block the execution of `rc.local`.

The commands between `until` and `done` will be repeated until the `ping` is successful, i.e., it gets a reply (i.e., the network is up).

Comment: For info `rc.local` was placed in `/etc` for me. I also had to ensure it was executable (`sudo chmod 775 /etc/rc.local`) and place `#!/bin/sh -e` at the top: https://askubuntu.com/questions/9853/how-can-i-make-rc-local-run-on-startup/401090#401090