# How do I get an RT3290 wireless card to work?

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, 16.04, ralink

After updating to 16.04 my Wifi card does not work anymore. And I have no idea what to do.

**lspci**

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
```

**sudo lshw -C network**

```
  *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 70:18:8b:81:85:09
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.4.0-21-generic firmware=0.37 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:19 memory:d0610000-d061ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 0c
       serial: a4:5d:36:c9:2b:c8
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=192.168.100.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:32 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d0500000-d0500fff memory:d0400000-d0403fff
```

**lsmod**

```
Module                  Size  Used by
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             172032  0
arc4                   16384  2
kvm                   536576  1 kvm_intel
snd_hda_codec_idt      57344  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_idt
rt2800pci              16384  0
rt2800mmio             20480  1 rt2800pci
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
rt2800lib              94208  2 rt2800pci,rt2800mmio
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
rt2x00pci              16384  1 rt2800pci
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
snd_hda_intel          36864  3
rt2x00mmio             16384  2 rt2800pci,rt2800mmio
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
rt2x00lib              57344  5 rt2x00pci,rt2800lib,rt2800pci,rt2800mmio,rt2x00mmio
aesni_intel           167936  0
mac80211              737280  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00pci,rt2800lib
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
uvcvideo               90112  0
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  2 aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
input_leds             16384  0
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
serio_raw              16384  0
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
videodev              176128  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
cfg80211              565248  2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
joydev                 20480  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
lpc_ich                24576  0
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
eeprom_93cx6           16384  1 rt2800pci
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
crc_ccitt              16384  1 rt2800lib
snd                    81920  17 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mei_me                 36864  0
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
shpchp                 36864  0
8250_fintek            16384  0
hp_accel               28672  0
lis3lv02d              20480  1 hp_accel
input_polldev          16384  1 lis3lv02d
hp_wireless            16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  3 hid_generic,usbhid
psmouse               126976  0
amdkfd                122880  1
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdkfd
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
radeon               1511424  1
i915                 1208320  4
ttm                    98304  1 radeon
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 i915,radeon
drm_kms_helper        139264  2 i915,radeon
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  2
drm                   360448  9 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,radeon
r8169                  81920  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
rtsx_pci               53248  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
mii                    16384  1 r8169
wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi
video                  40960  1 i915
fjes                   28672  0
```

**dmesg**

```
[   21.061887] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt3290.bin'
[   21.063536] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.37
[   22.678723] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_wait_wpdma_ready: Error - WPDMA TX/RX busy [0x00000068]
[   24.278717] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_wait_wpdma_ready: Error - WPDMA TX/RX busy [0x00000068]
[   24.278728] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800pci_set_device_state: Error - Device failed to enter state 4 (-5)
[   51.499485] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_wait_wpdma_ready: Error - WPDMA TX/RX busy [0x00000068]
[   53.099518] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800_wait_wpdma_ready: Error - WPDMA TX/RX busy [0x00000068]
[   53.099529] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800pci_set_device_state: Error - Device failed to enter state 4 (-5)
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Looks like buggy driver. The rt2800pci driver is working in Ubuntu15.10 with the latest update, but not in 16.04.

Comment: Its' really weird for me because after a few reboots it started to work :(

Comment: Did  you pull some updates via cable in between?

Comment: I tried to but there were no updates then.

Comment: Well, I discovered the problem on a 16.04 live USB stick when trying to connect to Wifi. The network manager sees the wifi network, but when I am trying to connect, it does not accept the passphrase. The client with Ubuntu 15.10 is working.

Comment: @hydrarulz I have the same problem. It was working in the beginning but suddenly it stopped. If you find any solution, please update.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I encountered the same problem on upgrading from 15.10 to 16.04. I managed to resolve the issue in my case by following the advice of others, specifically:

1. [How to install wifi driver Ralink RT3290](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545238/how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-rt3290][how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-rt3290]) and following [second answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545238/how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-rt3290/557427#557427), steps 1 to 8 about halfway down the post
2. I do have to enable my wireless card by opening a terminal window and issuing these two commands:

   `sudo ifconfig eno1 up`  and 
   `sudo service network-manager restart`

eno1 is the logical name for my wireless card (found in output of `sudo lshw -C network` command).

You can automate the two commands in step 2. by adding them to /etc/rc.local (see [How can I make "rc.local" run on startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9853/how-can-i-make-rc-local-run-on-startup][How) can I make “rc.local” run on startup?])

Comment: When I run `sudo ifconfig wlo1 up` I get the following error: SIOCSIFFLAGS: Input/output error

Comment: finally working solution +1

Answer (score 3):

I had the the same problem with my RT3090 wireless card after upgrading my laptop from 14.04 to 16.04.

After some messing around, I discovered that the Wifi would only work after resuming from suspend.

I finally seem to have fixed the problem by adding the following to the file `/etc/rc.local`:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo service network-manager restart
```

If your device is not "wlan0" you can substitute as required.

Comment: mine also only works after resume from suspend, but the rc.local solution doesnt work, nor does manually typing the commands

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by installing this driver:

http://onthim.blogspot.be/2015/06/install-ralink-rt3290-wi-fi-driver-on.html

Download information:

RT3290 Linux Driver
http://www.mediafire.com/download/l3zoch2y1hbcali/RT3290.tar.gz

For fedora users, please try the following:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/uk5u91dpts687la/RT3290_fedora.tar.gz

Updated package for Ubuntu 16.04 based distributions. Also suitable for Ubuntu 15.04 based distributions:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/pu4rejmmft8z9yr/RT3290_u16_v1.tar.gz

Installation instructions are in the download.

Comment: You should edit your answer to include the essential elements of installing the driver to make it more useful. If the link is ever removed, your answer will lose all it's usefulness.

Answer (score 0):

For me helped boot with advanced options and then selecting 4.4 kernel (upstart).
Also when booted with 4.2 kernel helped close lid, suspend and then open lid.

Answer (score 0):

This card works for me with linux kernel 4.4.0-33 from Ubuntu 16.04 repositories. No problems or special configuration needed.