# Problem with RT3290 Wifi Driver

Tags: 16.04

I can't even connect to wifi network currently in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 
I need to make RT3290 working

Please help :(

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We really need more information about your case. As suggested by @DavidFoerster, the output of the script would be very beneficial. Also, please update your question stating if you see the networks but cannot connect or if Ubuntu does not detect your wireless card.

Comment: Similar thing happened to me. Details are here.. https://askubuntu.com/q/924632/699522

Answer (score 1):

I had intermittent problems with the card (device not ready) and a weak signal. [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760838/wifi-ralink-does-not-work-on-ubuntu-16-04) helped me to solve my problem on a HP Pavilion G6, with a RT3290 wifi card.

The driver for the RT3290 is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545238/how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-rt3290) (it is mentioned in the link above). The second answer worked for me.

My signal strength and speed has also improved with the new driver.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried various solutions but I could not make the RT3290 wifi card work properly and stable. Today I decided to take a different approach. I bought 10$ wireless USB adapter such as
http://www.tendacn.com/en/product/download/W311MI.html
and my wifi connection get operational without any additional settings.

This adapter comes with a CD for Linux drivers, but it seems that for my HP 4740s they are not required. Probably Ubuntu 16.04 LTS have drivers for this device.

Comment: As stated in the link you provided "Model and hardware version availability varies by region" This would indicate to me that it's entirely possible that this answer could be less than helpful without the details. Perhasp you would be so kind as to obtain them as outlined [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html) and add them to your post. This would improve the quality of your answer.