# Can someone help me make my Ralink RT3290 Wireless card work properly on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: networking, drivers, ralink

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my HP Envy laptop and Wifi connection is terrible: when it works it is very slow and sometimes it does not work at all. No issue on Windows 10.

Here is some info:

```
sirfabel@bellaplx01:~$ uname -a
Linux bellaplx01 5.4.0-47-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 4 19:50:52 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


sirfabel@bellaplx01:~$ lspci | grep Ralink
07:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
07:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
```

It seems only rt28xx cards are supported:

```
sirfabel@bellaplx01:~$ lsmod | grep rt
rt2800pci              16384  0
rt2800mmio             20480  1 rt2800pci
rt2800lib             131072  2 rt2800mmio,rt2800pci
rt2x00pci              16384  1 rt2800pci
rt2x00mmio             16384  2 rt2800mmio,rt2800pci
rt2x00lib              61440  5 rt2x00mmio,rt2x00pci,rt2800mmio,rt2800pci,rt2800lib
```

Apparently this is a well-known issue, according to what I saw on the web... I tried to apply some patches I found on some forums, but none of them worked...

Can please someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions here https://askubuntu.com/questions/763772/problem-with-rt3290-wifi-driver ?

Comment: Yes, actually the patch proposed in this thread is deprecated. As it says: "The patch will work up to kernel version v4.14, it breaks on v4.15 onwards due to the change in the kernel timer implementations".

Comment: Can you see specific firmware **rt3290.bin** in your `/lib/firmware` directory?

Comment: Yes there is actually! How do I use that bin file?

Comment: That just means that it is already installed correctly. So let's try simply a different way of updating the firmware. Run these 4 commands separately `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y` then `sudo service fwupd start` then `sudo fwupdmgr refresh` then `sudo fwupdmgr update` and let us know if the Realtek device firmware is listed in the output.

Comment: Only my harddrive is listed on the output...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you with that card. I never had my wifi working perfectly even after long research, but i have found a few stuff that helped.

On what you provided, it seems that you have the right driver installed.

**Step 1: Wifi chanel**
You should try to change the chanel used by your router. If there are many wifi's available in your area there might be some interference.

Use `nmcli dev wifi` to see the available wifi networks and the chanel they use.
Then go to your router to change it.

**Step 2: Power Mangement**
When doing my research, I have found that power management is causing problems with the wifi. To see if it is activated use `iwconfig`. It should be `off` or `on`. If it is `on` see [How can I prevent iwconfig power management from being turned on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85214/how-can-i-prevent-iwconfig-power-management-from-being-turned-on) to turn it off.