# Ralink RT3290 WiFi card not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, 16.04, ralink

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a computer with a Ralink RT3290 wireless network card. After working fine for a day, the card just stopped working.  Apparently, the card is no longer supported in Linux so the only official drivers available are very old.

I have tried following the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760838/wifi-ralink-does-not-work-on-ubuntu-16-04),
[this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working) and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455030/ralink-rt3290-wifi-driver-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04) - even tried getting modified drivers from one of the commenters to get the driver to compile on the newer kernels (4.4.0 here). None of it worked.

`dmesg` reveals the following:

```
rt2800_wait_wpdma_ready: Error - WPDMA TX/RX busy [0x00000068]
rt2800_wait_wpdma_ready: Error - WPDMA TX/RX busy [0x00000068]
rt2800pci_set_device_state: Error - Device failed to enter state 4 (-5)
```

The card shows up when I do `lspci`:

```
Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
```

However, entering `lshw -C network` shows that the network is "DISABLED". `rfkill list` shows that the card is neither hard nor soft blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer after two days, posting it here for others to find. [This modified driver for Ubuntu 15.04](http://onthim.blogspot.se/2015/06/install-ralink-rt3290-wi-fi-driver-on.html) fixed the problem for me. Many thanks to the author! Those of you who, like me, are new to Linux, will appreciate how easy it is to install them.

Comment: it id working for now (1h) :) on 16.04

Comment: the link is not available now , please help me