# Xubuntu 16.04LTS Wifi disconnects

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, xubuntu, ralink

I have a HP G7-2325-dx laptop running on Xubuntu 16.04LTS.  Wifi is a Ralink RT3290.

My problem is that my wifi drops on its own and a window pops up asking for my wifi password which is already entered and starred out.  I press enter and it reconnects.  It doesn't seem to happen for any particular reason, just when I'm browsing the web or doing unrelated/offline stuff.

Here's some wifi output:

http://pastebin.com/fbcLq3ed

Comment: There is a similar post here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/792209/ralink-rt3290-wifi-card-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04