# WiFi connection unstable on Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: wireless, network-manager, internet

I have recently upgraded to 16.04.1. This problem did not begin immediately after upgrading, rather it showed up quite a few weeks after upgrading.
The issue is that the wifi connection to any network keeps getting disconnected at random. Moreover, wifi is very slow to connect to a network to begin with. 
After getting interrupted, it is very difficult to connect to a network again. 
I've browsed through MANY threads with a similar problem, but no proposed solution seems to work. Any help would be appreciated. 
I am a newbie on Linux, so please suggest edits and any required details.

Result of 'lspci -knn | grep Net -A2' terminal command:

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    DeviceName: Ralink RT3290LE  802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Ad
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo
```

> Adapter [103c:18ec]

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/768268/498541) can be of help.

Comment: @Karsus Why do you think s/he has an rtl8723be device?

Comment: @chili555 It's not about the particular device but the mindset behind how the problem got solved that really helps you fix the problem. For example he can use the commands from there to find what his device is and google the particular device to see what info he can find on Ubuntu/Linux compatibility.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Karsus That thread does seem to be very similar to my problem. However, I am a newbie on Linux so I don't know how to create the config file in /etc/pm/config.d/config. I went to that folder on my machine and tried right-clicking and selecting 'new empty document' but that option was not allowed. How can I do this?

Comment: @Pilot6 I have added the output as you asked.

Comment: @RohanSaxena Try using the terminal - it's a lot more versatile. [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/54222/498541) describes how to do it with nano. The reason you weren't allowed is because the /etc/ folder requires root access. From the terminal you can do `cd /etc/pm/config.d` and then `sudo nano config`.

Comment: @Karsus Thanks for the suggestion about the terminal, I learned how to use nano and will definitely keep that in mind. I tried the method that you suggested, but that does not resolve the connectivity issue. Do you have anything else in mind?

Comment: @RohanSaxena  Does [that](http://askubuntu.com/a/762244/498541) answer help?