# rt3290 wifi ubuntu reactivate 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I have this ralink 3290 wifi. it s not working well. I did the first reinstallation and had it working on the fly. now by rebooting wifi dies or is not alive at anyway.

here is some outputs

```
abcdef@abcdef-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~/Downloads$ lspci | grep Network
02:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
abcdef@abcdef-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~/Downloads$
```

```
abcdef@abcdef-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~/Downloads$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f0210000-f021ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 07
       serial: a0:d3:c1:63:0d:0d
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.0.105 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:31 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff memory:f0010000-f001ffff
abcdef@abcdef-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~/Downloads$
```

anybody to help me activate this correctly ? thank you by advance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation that was taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50498/discussion-on-question-by-jfab-rt3290-wifi-ubuntu-reactivate-16-04).

Comment: Could you please add the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2` to see which driver is in use and the output of `iw dev` to see if there is a interface name.

Comment: https://jpst.it/QOxn

Comment: Please edit your question and replace your long output with the short summary of `lspci -nnk | grep -i network -A2`, `rfkill list` and `iw dev | grep Interface`.

Comment: abcdef@abcdef-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -i network -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
 DeviceName: Ralink WLAN Ralink RT3290LE Roma 802.11bgn Wi-Fi
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
abcdef@abcdef-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ rfkill list
abcdef@abcdef-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ iw dev
abcdef@abcdef-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ iw dev | grep Interface
abcdef@abcdef-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$

Comment: https://justpaste.it/11qgr

Comment: Pleas add it well formated to your start post :D

Comment: i have limited space on this service. the paste link shows it clean

Comment: You are not able to edit your question?

Comment: maybe I can help... if you able to edit your question and paste the infos that I asked for (`lspci -nnk | grep -i network -A2`, `rfkill list wifi`, `lsmod`).

Comment: well i answer here your command line requests again. my question is why the wifi is not working ? I can not see the device in the options to list wifi networks...

Comment: here is the answer to your command line requests. My question is why wifi is still not working ok ?

Comment: https://jpst.it/QZ_T

Comment: anything new here ?

Comment: @JFab Why you didn't answer my question?

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: @JFab, why are you not able to edit your question to add all the informations I asked for?

Comment: well you have  the answer listed in the paste link ... what do u need more ?

Comment: or what is your question / request ?

Comment: I need that output in a well formed question. With respect to your question, I mean the part above all the comments.

Comment: Hello I gave you all the details output on the paste link upwise. what went wrong please state me ?

Comment: is more easy actually I have now ordered an usb network wifi dongle as this sheeet of ralink won t get up....

Comment: here comes your output again

Comment: https://jpst.it/Rhy1

Comment: if u r still here

Comment: are you here my friend ?

Comment: See my answer here http://askubuntu.com/a/879211/45639

Answer (score 0):

I am using asus X450cc and my wifi card it rt3290. This is what worked for me

I downloaded the rt3290 Driver from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/l3zoch2y1hbcali/RT3290.tar.gz), extracted it and entered the directory and ran

```
sudo ./run.sh
```

This requires a working ethernet connection.

Then I also tried [How to install wifi driver Ralink RT3290](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545238/how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-rt3290) and [How do I get an RT3290 wireless card to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760838/how-do-i-get-an-rt3290-wireless-card-to-work)

Then I tried:

```
rfkill unblock all
```

I also tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer b43-fwcutter
sudo reboot
```

Finally I tried:

```
sudo ifconfig enp3s0f0 up  #(here this is my logical name of wifi change it to your wifi name)
sudo pm-suspend
```

Now my wifi is working, although I still have a tiny problem; every time I boot into Ubuntu I need to suspend and resume, only then does my wifi work.