# Wifi not detecting any networks (RT3290) in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless

I have gone through most answers on this topic and yet, my system is not able to detect any Wifi networks.

Upon rebooting, it does not even show the option of Wifi on the dropdown of the wifi icon on the top bar (although the Wifi icon is there), it just has the option of `Enable Networking`.

If I run -

`sudo ifconfig eno1 up` (eno1 is the logical name of my wifi)

and `sudo service network-manager restart`

then it gives the option of `Enable Wifi` on the dropdown of the Wifi icon, but still it does not detect any networks.

This is the output of `nmcli dev` -

`DEVICE  TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION 
enp8s0  ethernet  unavailable  --

eno1    wifi      unavailable  --

lo      loopback  unmanaged    --`

This is the output for `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` -

`0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    DeviceName:

    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2860
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes`

And this is the output for `sudo lshw -C network` -

`*-network

       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: enp8s0
       version: 07
       serial: 64:51:06:a9:02:a2
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b5600000-b5600fff memory:b5400000-b5403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 00
       serial: 9c:ad:97:0e:ec:8d
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=RALINK WLAN latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=Ralink STA
       resources: irq:16 memory:b5510000-b551ffff`

Comment: Please edit your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Redbob I have edited the question to add the output of the command you mentioned. Please have a look

Comment: You have a hardware block to wireless device. It could be drivers or blacklist issue. There are some issues dealing with it: [760838](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760838/how-do-i-get-an-rt3290-wireless-card-to-work) and [253632](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working), for example.

Comment: @Redbob thanks. I have already tried the answers on the first link you mention and they don't seem to help. The problem with the answers in the second link is that they require a wired connection to the laptop and in my case that does not work either!!

Comment: @user1993 The purpose of the "wired connection" is having internet so you can download and install the packages. It can be any other, even a USB tethered connection from Android or other.