# network UNCLAIMED Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, realtek, realtek-wireless

I was facing some issues with wifi disconnection. So I followed some askubuntu forum answers and solved the problem by manually installing the wifi device. But still I had to follow the first answer of this question
([How do I get an RT3290 wireless card to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760838/how-do-i-get-an-rt3290-wireless-card-to-work)) to make it work on every start up.

Then suddenly it stopped working now. Now when I run `sudo lshw -C network` it gives me this error.

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b5510000-b551ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 08
       serial: a0:1d:48:d1:23:d9
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-2_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=192.168.1.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b5404000-b5404fff memory:b5400000-b5403fff
```

it says network UNCLAIMED. Why is that ? How can I solve that issue ?

When I run `lspci` it shows me my wifi adapter model as

```
08:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
```

I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760838/how-do-i-get-an-rt3290-wireless-card-to-work). But it says that it will work when secure boot is disabled. But the thing is I've already disabled secure boot and I was working fine about two hours ago.

How can I solve this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try using a USB WiFi adapter and then if that works replace the wireless card in your pc or laptop. I have a HP that had a bad Intel card and that was not compatible and I replaced the card and now it works.

Comment: But it was working few hours ago. The only thing I did is turning off my laptop and turning back on after few hours

Comment: So the problem persists after reboot? `UNCLAIMED` is not the same as in the link you posted `DISABLED`.  I think `UNCLAIMED` in this context means you have a driver, but it has not claimed the device. Probably you can manually `bind` the device to the module / driver.  `lspci -knn` should  give you the driver name. Than use that in `tree /sys/ | grep module_name`. This should give u the path to the driver. Than as root `echo "0000:08:00.0" > /sys/path/to/driver/bind`.

Comment: @AlexOnLinux When I run the command `tree /sys/ | grep module_name` with my module name this returns nothing.

Comment: @Pankaja Paranavitharana could you please Edit your question and add the output of `lspci -knn`

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the kernel version, i. e. the output of `uname -a`? Also, how *exactly* did you (try to) install the kernel module with the device driver and what happened when you did? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. Thanks.

Comment: I was frustrated and reinstalled Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same problem today. Turned off my laptop after finishing with my job and than turning it back on when I got home. Ubuntu wasn't able to find any wi-fi. I know that this might sound stupid, but try turning off (not restarting) your pc, leave it for a few seconds or a minute and then turn it back on. This, no matter how stupid it sounds, just solved my problem and I'm able to use wifi again (I also ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`, which I don't think helped solving this issue, but updating can't be bad).
Just for the record, I was also restarting my laptop few times but it didn't helped.

Hope this helps you.