# Start a command on boot

Tags: boot, command-line, ubuntu-mate

I'm on Ubuntu Mate,  and I would like the system to run the command `homebridge`at boot.

Do I just need to

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

and add this

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
homebridge
exit 0
```

Comment: You are here so I'am guessing it didn't work. Make sure rc.local is executable and owned by root.

Comment: But 16.04 and later seem to have no `/etc/rc.local`, so that post needs an updated answer I think

Comment: Yes, but I'd have to recommend that you use **full system path** for `rc.local` and `cron`.

Comment: Are you asking this question because it's not working, or are you asking this question because you want to make sure you've got it correct before you reboot?

Comment: @Zanna I have a 16.04 VM (not upgraded) which has `rc.local`

Comment: @muru oh oops it's only 16.10; I only have a `/lib/systemd/system/rc.local.service` and I am not sure how we are supposed to manage now. (My thought was from [No \`rc.local\` in 16.10, so how can I add a command to set brightness on boot?](//askubuntu.com/q/846212) ) So I still think we need an update to the dupe target.

Comment: @Zanna for a single command, perhaps a new systemd unit: http://askubuntu.com/a/719157/158442

Comment: @muru indeed :) actually reading the file I mentioned [it looks like you could just create `/etc/rc.local` and make it executable](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23850544/)

Comment: @Zanna yes, that works (remember to add an `exit 0` to it so that failed commands don't cause boot to hang or fail)

Comment: @muru thanks! I added some notes to the accepted answer to the dupe target and voted to close this.

Answer (score 1):

On systems with systemd in use rc.local might be ignored. 
In this post there's suggestions how to check that rc.local is really executed.

[How can I make "rc.local" run on startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9853/how-can-i-make-rc-local-run-on-startup)

And make sure your remove the ">" signs in your example.

Comment: +1 it's also important to consider whether the executable is in the default `PATH` (using an absolute path is a good idea, just in case) and what it does (or, more specifically, what environment and/or services it needs in order to run - such as a GUI/user session or networking services)