# script.sh: source: not found

Tags: bash, scripts, autostart

I have a question about rc.local. I created a script **auto.sh** and it includes:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $home
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash 
xterm -hold -e "/opt/ros/indigo/bin/roscore" &
xterm -hold -e "/opt/ros/indigo/bin/roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch"
exit 0
```

My purpose is run to this script automatically using rc.local. rc.local file located at:

```
/etc/init.d/rc.local
```

**rc.local** file includes the code :

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

sudo ./auto.sh
sh '/home/moguztas/auto.sh'

exit 0
```

This code is executable. I followed the steps at [How can I make "rc.local" run on startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9853/how-can-i-make-rc-local-run-on-startup?noredirect=1&lq=1) .

But when I check the code using:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rc.local start
```

it gives a error in terminal as given below:

```
./auto.sh: 4: ./auto.sh: source: not found
```

Also, in XTerm terminal errors are given like :
[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2tkl.png)
[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dT3F.png)

Could you tell what is my problem ?

Comment: `sh` on Ubuntu is the dash shell, not bash. It has no such command as `source`

Comment: The error states it cannot find/import the module roslaunch. That should set you on right track ?

Comment: NO, it states that it can not find the command `source` ..

Comment: @Soren: I was referring to the error2 question. Zanna already addressed the source-question.  But for completeness, the command: sh '/home/moguztas/auto.sh'   should be changed to: bash '/home/moguztas/auto.sh'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're invoking `/bin/sh`, which, on Ubuntu, is a much simpler shell than `/bin/bash`, and lacks the `source` command.
2. At the time `rc.local` runs, is `/opt/ros/indigo/` mounted? If it is your encrypted `HOME` directory, it won't exist until you log in.
3. At the time `rc.local` runs, the X server has not yet started, so running an `xterm` won't work.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I change `/bin/sh` with `/bin/bash`, my problem is solved. But I have another problem now. `rc.local` does not automatically when computer start up. What must I do for this ?

Comment: Ask a separate question, or reread my answer.