# Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Ubuntu 18.04 wifi signal very weak

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, atheros

I've googled a bunch of threads and tried many methods therein but still didn't solve the problem.
The following one is what I think most useful but still doesn't work to my Dell G3 3590 (2019 version).

[Qualcomm Atheros weak Wifi signal on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033679/qualcomm-atheros-weak-wifi-signal-on-ubuntu-18-04/1036178#1036178)

Comment: Use `nmcli dev wifi` to see (in color) the signal strength of nearby WiFi devices.

Comment: This is how it looks like when I use nmcli dev wifi.
https://imgur.com/1FMyyvl
This is how it looks like when I run speed test from google fiber. 
https://imgur.com/57t66eX
When I run it in Windows 10 with the same laptop.
https://imgur.com/ShBGYrb
Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Disabling bluetooth is reported to improve WiFi in some cases. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, all of my previous tests were running with Bluetooth disabled :s Thanks for the suggestion!