# Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 wireless not working on lenovo with Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers

I did ran the commands in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033679/qualcomm-atheros-weak-wifi-signal-on-ubuntu-18-04) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701350/qualcomm-atheros-qca9377-wireless-not-working-on-lenovo-with-14-04-3) posts, but got the following errors which chili555 mentioned but still my signal keeps being weak.

Tried changing **config_enabled** to **x2apic_enabled** with no luck.

EDIT: After following chili555's answer i ran the -uname -r command and it returned this

> 4.15.0-118-generic

So I downloaded v4.14-rc2/ and it gave this error:

> /home/yanes/backports-4.14-rc2-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/htt_rx.c: In function ‘ath10k_htt_rx_alloc’:
> /home/yanes/backports-4.14-rc2-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/htt_rx.c:510:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘setup_timer’; did you mean ‘sk_stop_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
> setup_timer(timer, ath10k_htt_rx_ring_refill_retry, (unsigned long)htt);
> ^~~~~~~~~~~
> sk_stop_timer
> cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
> scripts/Makefile.build:330: recipe for target '/home/yanes/backports-4.14-rc2-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/htt_rx.o' failed
> make[8]: *** [/home/yanes/backports-4.14-rc2-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/htt_rx.o] Error 1
> scripts/Makefile.build:604: recipe for target '/home/yanes/backports-4.14-rc2-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k' failed
> make[7]: *** [/home/yanes/backports-4.14-rc2-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k] Error 2
> scripts/Makefile.build:604: recipe for target '/home/yanes/backports-4.14-rc2-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath' failed
> make[6]: *** [/home/yanes/backports-4.14-rc2-1/drivers/net/wireless/ath] Error 2
> scripts/Makefile.build:604: recipe for target '/home/yanes/backports-4.14-rc2-1/drivers/net/wireless' failed
> make[5]: *** [/home/yanes/backports-4.14-rc2-1/drivers/net/wireless] Error 2
> Makefile:1585: recipe for target '*module*/home/yanes/backports-4.14-rc2-1' failed
> make[4]: *** [*module*/home/yanes/backports-4.14-rc2-1] Error 2
> Makefile.build:6: recipe for target 'modules' failed
> make[3]: *** [modules] Error 2
> Makefile.real:88: recipe for target 'modules' failed
> make[2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701350/qualcomm-atheros-qca9377-wireless-not-working-on-lenovo-with-14-04-3): *** [modules] Error 2
> Makefile:40: recipe for target 'modules' failed
> make[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033679/qualcomm-atheros-weak-wifi-signal-on-ubuntu-18-04): *** [modules] Error 2
> Makefile:30: recipe for target 'default' failed
> make: *** [default] Error 2

EDIT 2: My laptop freezes unless I turn the wi-fi off, tried installing older version instead of newer (v4.1.1) by disabling wi-fi but It returns that I have no permission? Here's the output.

> make[2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701350/qualcomm-atheros-qca9377-wireless-not-working-on-lenovo-with-14-04-3): execvp: ./lxdialog/check-lxdialog.sh: Permission denied
> make[2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701350/qualcomm-atheros-qca9377-wireless-not-working-on-lenovo-with-14-04-3): execvp: ./lxdialog/check-lxdialog.sh: Permission denied
> make[2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701350/qualcomm-atheros-qca9377-wireless-not-working-on-lenovo-with-14-04-3): 'conf' is up to date.
> make[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033679/qualcomm-atheros-weak-wifi-signal-on-ubuntu-18-04): execvp: ./kconf/conf: Permission denied
> Makefile.real:41: recipe for target 'defconfig-ath10k' failed
> make[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033679/qualcomm-atheros-weak-wifi-signal-on-ubuntu-18-04): *** [defconfig-ath10k] Error 127
> Makefile:40: recipe for target 'defconfig-ath10k' failed
> make: *** [defconfig-ath10k] Error 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A backport file from 2015 is unlikely to successfully compile in more modern kernel versions. Please note the answer at the link you gave that says, in part:

> Before executing the wget command check for you linux kernel version.
>
> ```
> $ uname -r
> ```
>
> Then go to https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/
> and check for the closest kernel version available there and then
> download the backports tar file using the following command.

For example, if uname -r returns 5.4.0-48-generic, then select the backport version that closely matches. In this case select https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v5.4.56/backports-5.4.56-1.tar.gz

It compiles without error on my 5.4.0-48 machine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I updated my post as I'm still facing errors.

Comment: Rather than a release candidate (rc2), please try 4.19.112. Does it still fail?

Comment: Now wifi doesn't work at all. what's more screen freezes at startup

Comment: I doubt that the freeze is related to backports as ‘make’ never succeeded and you never were able to continue to ‘sudo make install’.

Comment: I didn't do anything else though. It has to be that.

Comment: Could you help me fix this?

Comment: Can you enter Recovery Mode at the GRUB menu? Does ‘modinfo  ath10k_pci’ tell us what version is installed? Backport?

Comment: If the filename is /lib/modules/xxx-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_pci.ko where xxx is your kernel version, then that is the default and no backport is installed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113980/discussion-between-giannhs-ker-and-chili555).

Answer (score 0):

### First Method:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware
```

### 2nd Method

(this method solved my issue)

```
sudo apt remove broadcom-sta-dkms bcmwl-kernel-source 
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
```

### 3rd Method:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt install fwupd

sudo fwupdmgr refresh && sudo fwupdmgr update

sudo reboot
```

### 4th Method :

After few days of testing, it looks like a firmware problem to me. I've tested all the ones available at `https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/tree/master/QCA9377/hw1.0` and I experienced the very same issue with all the three API6 files (i.e. firmware-6.bin_*).

The latest (in terms of release date) API5 file firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00023-QCATFSWPZ-1 seemed to work much better but I still experienced the issue after few solid hours.

Eventually, the file firmware-5.bin_CNSS.TF.1.0-00267-QCATFSWPZ-1 seems to be the most stable on my Lenovo Ideapad 320 using:

Network controller: **Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)**

So try renaming the existing firmware-5.bin and firmware-6.bin files under `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/` and use the firmware version I've mentioned. In other words...

```
 cd /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/
```

```
sudo mv firmware-5.bin firmware-5.bin.orig
```

```
sudo mv firmware-6.bin firmware-6.bin.orig
```

```
 sudo wget "https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/blob/master/QCA9377/hw1.0/CNSS.TF.1.0/firmware-5.bin_CNSS.TF.1.0-00267-QCATFSWPZ-1?raw=true" -O firmware-5.bin
```

*Now load the new firmware and double-check*

```
 sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci
```

```
 sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
```

```
 sudo dmesg | grep ath10k
```

***output:***

```
ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: qca9377 hw1.1 target 0x05020001 chip_id 0x003821ff sub 17aa:0901
ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 0 tracing 0 dfs 0 testmode 0
ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware ver CNSS.TF.1.0-00267-QCATFSWPZ-1 api 5 features ignore-otp crc32 d6b81b3c
ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board-2.bin
ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 8aedfa4a
ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: unsupported HTC service id: 1536
ath10k_pci 0000:01:00.0: htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
```

Make sure the version id just next to firmware ver matches.

I hope this trick will solve that annoying issue for you too ;)

Comment: Chilli555 already solved the problem I had. Thank you for your answer, I will use it if need be.