# /etc/rc.local - is it running?

Tags: boot, bash

I put the the following in /etc/rc.local, to enable the Scroll Lock LED on my keyboard - it doesn't seem to take effect:

```
#!/bin/bash

# enable scroll lock LED
xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'

exit 0
```

I did do `sudo chmod a+x /etc/rc.local` to make it executable, and the script seems to work OK (makes the Scroll Lock LED work) when I execute `/etc/rc.local` from the terminal.

I know there are other ways to get scripts to run on boot, but I want to understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make /etc/rc.local run on startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9853/how-can-i-make-etc-rc-local-run-on-startup)

Comment: Look at the systemd answer of 9853.

Comment: @ubfan1: Not directly, anyway. The answer here (from Pilot6) is clear and direct - much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command won't work for two reasons:

1. You need to use full path to `xmodmap`.
2. The command needs a user session, that is not started yet when `rc.local` is executed.

You an add the command to "Startup Applications".

Comment: That works - thanks!. For those who want to know how to do it from the command line, "Startup Applications" creates a .desktop folder in "~/.config/autostart".