# after each reboot I need to assign swap manually and /etc/rc.local doesn't get triggered

Tags: bash, swap, reboot

After every reboot, I'm just seeing one swap in my system.

```bash
$ sudo swapon --show
NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file   2G   0B   -2
```

So in `/etc/rc.local` I've put this piece of instruction:

```
# activate two secondary swap of size 16GiB + 16GiB
sudo swapon /swapfile1
sudo swapon /swapfilesecondary
```

Still after restarting I get only one swap with 2 GiB of memory. How can I fix this?

**NB:** If I manually execute these two commands, then I get the desired output:

```
$ sudo swapon --show
NAME               TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile          file   2G   0B   -2
/swapfile1         file  16G   0B   -3
/swapfilesecondary file  16G   0B   -4
```

Comment: Make sure it is executable, and ends with `exit 0`. [How can I make /etc/rc.local run on startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9853/how-can-i-make-etc-rc-local-run-on-startup)