# How to cleanly launch a GUI app via the Terminal?

Tags: command-line, gui

Some GUI apps launch cleanly via the Terminal command line, but some don't, and they cause the Terminal to wait for the app to terminate. Even then, some don't "release" the command line.

The mysterious ampersand `&` suffix seems to cause the terminal to put the process into the background (but I'm not sure what happens there).

Is there a way to launch an app via the Terminal so that there is no "hang on" effect, just like launching something via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>?

I'd like to have the command line available again immediately, without something still in the background and printing in the terminal.

Comment: At the request of htorque, I deleted his answer that you accepted. Please could you pick another answer (you will have to unselect htorque's first - should be lurking at the bottom of the page in red)

Comment: The method to deal with a *Program-already-running* (as outlined by con-f-use) is good for that situation, but as my primary question was about *clean-launching with no terminal clutter*, I've accepted `screen` (mentioned by Oli and RobinJ). I am impressed by its capability; after reading about it and trying it out... It only requires the typing of: `screen -d -m gedit` (or `screen gedit` then `Ctrl+a d` to detach)... and I still have full access to gedit's terminal view (for warning messages etc) at any time via `screen -r` even if I have closed the original terminal window in the meantime...

Comment: BTW, some of the things you're attributing to the terminal are actually done by the shell, for example interpreting the `&` command suffix. This might be helpful for clarification: [What is the difference between Terminal, Console, Shell, and Command Line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/506510/301745)

Comment: sudo -E gedit /tmp/a.txt

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In gedit's case, I just keep a copy open all the time. As long as you have an existing copy running, launching `gedit` calls from the terminal and then closing the terminal won't kill gedit.

For other things, what other people have said would work too. I'm a fan of `nohup`... But if you need a terminal you can detach but then re-attach to, you want to look at `screen`.

1. Run it in a terminal and then run something that keeps pushing output. I use the Django development server but `irssi` or even `watch uptime` would be good examples.
2. Kill the terminal and start a new one.
3. Run `screen -r` and BOOM, you're back in.

`screen` is a lot bigger than that and you can combine it with `byobu` for a better terminal experience. Read around.

Comment: This is the first real insight I've had as to what screen does/can do... thanks for the terminal tip...

Comment: screen is no longer available, but tmux can replace screen. (tmux to start a new tmux session, ctrl+b, then press d to deatach, and tmux attach to reattach)

Answer (score 90):

Suppose `gedit` is the program you want to run detached (aka. "disowned", "disentangled", "decoupled"). There are different ways depending on what you want to do exactly:

### Program already running

#### Disown:

`disown -h` is the way to go if you want to do that with an already running program (i.e. if you forgot to `nohup` it). You first have to stop it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. Then you can put in in the background using `bg [jobId]` (e.g. `bg 1`). You get a list of running jobs with their jobId using `jobs`. After that you can decouple it from terminal using `disown -h %[jobId]`. Example terminal session:

```
$ gedit 
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 gedit
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 gedit
$ bg 1
[1]+ gedit &
$ disown -h %1
$ exit
```

### Program not started yet

#### nohup

`nohup` is not always present on all machines. If you know you want to decouple beforehand you would use:

```
nohup gedit &
```

Maybe you will want to redirect the shell output as well and your program a pseudo input source, so: `nohup ./myprogram > foo.out 2> bar.err < /dev/null &`. You would want to redirect the output to either not be annoyed by it or to use it later. The null-input can help to prevent hickups in ssh an such.

#### Subshell:

You can achieve a similar effect by

```
$ (geany >/dev/null 2>&1 &)
```

The brackets open a new subshell to run gedit in. The `>/dev/null 2>&1` redirects the shell output to nowhere (suppressing the output). And the `&` at the end puts the process in the background.

#### Terminal multiplexing

Also terminal multiplexing using [screen](http://jmcpherson.org/screen.html) or [byobu](http://dj-bri-t.net/2009/10/gnu-screen-and-byobu-made-easy/). You basically run the program in a terminal of its own. I can really recommend byobu for other reasons too. Below is a list of boybu-shortcuts that might come in handy for your first steps:

Useful:

- <kbd>F2</kbd>              Create a new window
- <kbd>F3</kbd>              Move to the next window
- <kbd>F4</kbd>              Move to the previous window
- <kbd>F6</kbd>              Detach from the session and logout
- <kbd>Shift-F6</kbd>        Detach from the session, but do not logout
- <kbd>F7</kbd>              Enter scrollback/search mode
- <kbd>Ctrl-F5</kbd>         Reconnect any SSH/GPG sockets or agents

Less useful:

- <kbd>Shift-F2</kbd>        Split the screen horizontally
- <kbd>Ctrl-F2</kbd>         Split the screen vertically
- <kbd>Shift-F3</kbd>        Move focus to the next split
- <kbd>Shift-F4</kbd>        Move focus to the previous split
- <kbd>Shift-F5</kbd>        Collapse all splits
- <kbd>F5</kbd>              Refresh all status notifications
- <kbd>F8</kbd>              Rename the current window
- <kbd>F9</kbd>              Launch the Byobu Configuration Menu
- <kbd>F12</kbd>             GNU Screen's Escape Key
- <kbd>Alt-Pageup</kbd>      Scroll back through this window's history
- <kbd>Alt-Pagedown</kbd>    Scroll forward through this window's history
- <kbd>Ctrl-a-!</kbd>        Toggle all of Byobu's keybindings on or off

#### The 'at' daemon and others

`at` is a nice useful little tool to run a command at a scheduled time. It can be 'misused' to detach a command from the shell:

```
echo './myprogram myoption1 myoption2' | at now
```

Also you can look into `setsid` and `start-stop-daemon`, but the other methods should suffice.

Comment: Tip: if there's just one job, the job ID is optional, e.g. instead of `bg %1` you can just type `bg`.

Answer (score 30):

To start an application and detach it from the launched terminal use zsh's &!.

```
firefox &!
```

Comment: Good to know, but that seems to be zsh-only. In bash you'd have to manually run `disown <pid-of-command>` after starting the command in the background.

Comment: Interesting... I'm going to look into zsh, but as a Linux newbie, I'll stick with bash for now... Thanks

Comment: what does the exclamation mark do ?

Comment: The ! will break the application process from the terminal process so that you can close the terminal without the application that was launched from closing. It seems to be a zsh thing, but handy.

Comment: But  this worked in bash too @htorque .... So I guess it's not a problem.

Comment: Simple and clean!

Comment: I think its worth mentioning that this is not compatible with all shells. For me, it worked with BASH4 and ZSH. imo, cleanest answer on the thread

Answer (score 25):

> The mysterious ampersand "&" suffix, seems to cause the terminal to put the process into the background... (but I'm not sure what happens there).

It does, and is often what you want.  If you forget to use &, you can suspend the program with ctrl-z then place it in the background with the bg command — and continue to use that shell.

The process' stdin, stdout, and stderr are still connected to the terminal; you can redirect those from/to /dev/null or any other file (e.g. save an output log somewhere), as desired:

```bash
some-program </dev/null &>/dev/null &
# &>file is bash for 1>file 2>&1
```

You can see the process in jobs, bring it back to the foreground (fg command), and send it signals (kill command).

Some graphical programs will detach from the terminal; if that's the case, when you run the command "normally" you'll notice it starts the graphical program *and* "exits".

---

Here's [a short script](http://bitbucket.org/kniht/scraps/src/fdf116645350/shell/runbg), you can place it in [~/bin](https://askubuntu.com/q/9848), which I named runbg:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
[ $# -eq 0 ] && {  # $# is number of args
  echo "$(basename $0): missing command" >&2
  exit 1
}
prog="$(which "$1")"  # see below
[ -z "$prog" ] && {
  echo "$(basename $0): unknown command: $1" >&2
  exit 1
}
shift  # remove $1, now $prog, from args
tty -s && exec </dev/null      # if stdin is a terminal, redirect from null
tty -s <&1 && exec >/dev/null  # if stdout is a terminal, redirect to null
tty -s <&2 && exec 2>&1        # stderr to stdout (which might not be null)
"$prog" "$@" &  # $@ is all args
```

I look up the program ($prog) before redirecting so errors in locating it can be reported.  Run it as "runbg your-command args..."; you can still redirect stdout/err to a file if you need to save output somewhere.

Except for the redirections and error handling, this is equivalent to [htorque's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10547/how-to-clean-launch-a-gui-app-via-the-terminal-so-it-doesnt-wait-for-terminati/10558#10558).

Comment: Okay, thanks... It seems that `ctrl-z` (suspend) gives me access to the command line again, but blanks out the GUI until I issue `bg` which seems to un-suspend it. (makes sense)...  Is there another command by which I can detach the GUI... Aha! I see now what you mean by `sighals (kill command)`...  (interesting things these signals).. I used a code snippet to make `dd` progressively output it stats.. and it used `kill` + a SIGNAL...  Is there a specific SIGNAL to detach a "job"?

Comment: I just noticed your comment to Rick's answer... I tried  `disown `jobs -p gedit`` and it seemd to remove the job.... (but I got system messages in the Terminal when I manually closed gedit... but I think I've got a screwed-up Terminal at the moment... too much **experimenting** :(

Comment: @fred: Jobs are managed by the shell, so no signal can control that.  You may find it works best to start several shells — several GUI terminals allow tabs and you can use screen or tmux.

Comment: @fred: better don't run `jobs -p command` if you have multiple instances of one command running in the background at a time. you can use `jobs` to find the right job id and then do `jobs -p <job-id>` to get the job's PID. Personally I find the version with the subshell a lot easier. ;-)

Comment: @htorque, fred: You can run disown without parameters to have bash disown the last job: `gedit & disown`

Comment: @Roger: right, manpage readers know it better. :P

Comment: All good stuff... It seems to me that `(gedit &)` is **effectively** the same as `gedit & disown`... I'll use one on even-numbered days, and the other on odd-numbered days, until I settle on one; probably the one with is easier to type... Thanks :)

Comment: @Roger Pate: Your answer came to my attention today (after 8 months), and I finally got around to trying (and understanding) your script..  It certainly takes care of  spurious messages in the terminal widows, and is very easy to type.. thanks..

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 20):

Use `nohup`

> nohup is a program that runs a given command with hangup signals
>   ignored, so that the command can continue running in the background
>   after its parent process terminates. See the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/nohup.1.html)

For example:

```
nohup gedit something
```

Comment: What is `nohup`? Please elaborate.

Comment: nohup is a program that runs a given command with hangup signals ignored, so that the command can continue running in the background after its parent process terminates. See the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/nohup.1.html)

Comment: Actually I think my answer is incorrect here. On further thought, `nohup` should be used in this scenario.

Comment: I tried `nohup` and It's work for me, so thank you for help. :) Marketing this answer as accepted. :)

Comment: When an interactive shell receive a SIGHUP signal, can send (or not, depending on settings) a SIGHUP signal to all of its childs. This can happen (or not, again) when a terminal is closed. A child not ready to handle such a signal will execute the default action, i.e. exit. The `nohup` application (and the `disown` bash builtin) do not allow the signal to reach the application.

Comment: One thing to be careful of is that `nohup` creates a file in the current directory called `nohup.out`. See the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/nohup.1.html) for more details. I prefer `disown` for this reason, and for the fact that `disown` works after you launch `gedit`.

Comment: As @Filmm commented, by defaut it redirects output to a file called nohuo.out in the folder where the command is run, which in some situation can be a security concern (in my example, a folder where I develop locally a website and then synchronize regularly with the actual website : you do not want your nohup.out to be put on a website)

Answer (score 4):

Open the terminal, type *screen*, type the command you want to run, close the terminal. The program should keep on running in the *GNU Screen* session.

Comment: What exactly is GNU Screen?

Comment: If I get the idea correctly, it's a kind of window manager for the command line. It allows you to run more than one program at once in a command line interface session.

Comment: Byobu?

Comment: Something like that, only Byobu is easier to use. If I am npot mistaken, Byobu is just an easier interface for GNU Screen.

Comment: It *ALMOST* works perfectly in BASH. The only minor complaint being that you get notifications of background status when the process starts and stops. Linux is so darned strange coming from windows world. You would think this would totally be A Thing.Just start the darned thing, and stop spewing status messages from the dark ages of computing that truly nobody cares about all over my terminal. lol.

Answer (score 2):

## xdg-open

Have a look at this general-purpose utility: https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open

This will open a relative location in your file manager.

```
 $ xdg-open .
```

This will open a pdf file in a pdf reader.

```
 $ xdg-open foo.pdf
```

You can even provide web URLs

```
$ xdg-open www.google.com
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
$ (nohup gedit 2>/dev/null &)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a lot of people figured, nohup is the thing to consider.
But nohup stills remains open on the terminal and displays the program activity on the terminal which is irritating. You can just close the terminal after that to avoid so.
I found out a very simple workaround which I use.

```
nohup gedit & exit
```

And that's it. It opens gedit and closes the terminal when gedit starts up. As gedit is not associated with the terminal now, it stays active.

Answer (score 0):

This works even inside a script (Like aliases, the '&' trailer is not normally allowed in scripts because they are not interactive):

```
bash -i >/dev/null 2>&1 <<<'nohup gedit &'
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$ (some-program &) &>/dev/null

# Examples:
$ (gedit &) &>/dev/null
$ (google-chrome &) &>/dev/null
```