# How can I run program from terminal without killing the program when closing the terminal

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clean launch a GUI app via the Terminal (so it doesn't wait for termination)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10547/how-to-clean-launch-a-gui-app-via-the-terminal-so-it-doesnt-wait-for-terminatio)

Tho whole problem is that if I run a program from Gnome Terminal(e.g. `gedit something`) the program Gedit runs, but if I close Gnome Terminal, the program Gedit closes too.

I know <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> exist, but I want to use Gnome Terminal.

Any help is really appreciated. :)