# Run application in specific X server or VNC port

Tags: vnc, xserver, kiosk, remote-x-session

I have an application that I'd like to run, yet I'd like it to be visible only through a certain VNC port.

I don't want the app to show up on the normal Ubuntu desktop. I want the app to run "in the background", and be viewable through VNC only. And when connected to this "alternate X server", the end-user wouldn't see any menu bars, no window decorations.. Just the app.

Come to think of it, what I'm asking for is a sort of kiosk-mode for only a certain app, accessible through VNC.

Is this possible or am I really reaching here?

Thanks!

*<sub>Note that the app I wish to run in this fashion is written in Java. It is a JNLP file.</sub>*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully accomplished this. Here's how.

---

Install the necessary software.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer xvfb x11vnc vnc-java blackbox xterm
```

Set a password for the VNC connection.

```
x11vnc -storepasswd
```

Create a script file to run with cron.

```
sudo nano /sflowtrend.sh
```

These are the contents of the file.

```
#!/bin/bash

log="/sflowtrend.log"

echo "Closing existing sFlowTrend windows gracefully." > $log
DISPLAY=:1 wmctrl -c "sFlowTrend"
sleep 5


echo "Killing all existing instances of java, Xvfb, and x11vnc." >> $log
for i in {1..3} ; do
        killall -q java
        killall -q x11vnc
        killall -q Xvfb
        echo "Iteration $i of kill cycle complete." >> $log
        sleep 2
done

echo >> $log

Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1200x800x24+32 -ac &
echo "Fake X launched." >> $log

x11vnc -display :1 --nocursor --httpdir /usr/share/vnc-java --httpport 6789 --usepw --forever --quiet --shared &
echo "VNC launched." >> $log

DISPLAY=:1 blackbox &
echo "BlackBok launched." >> $log

DISPLAY=:1 javaws /home/administrator/Downloads/sFlowTrend.jnlp &
echo "sFlowTrend (Java) launched." >> $log

echo >> $log

echo "Sleeping for one minute." >> $log
sleep 10
echo "Sleeping for fifty seconds." >> $log
sleep 10
echo "Sleeping for forty seconds." >> $log
sleep 10
echo "Sleeping for thirty seconds." >> $log
sleep 10
echo "Sleeping for twenty seconds." >> $log
sleep 10
echo "Sleeping for ten seconds." >> $log
sleep 10

echo >> $log

DISPLAY=:1 wmctrl -r "sFlowTrend" -b add,fullscreen
echo "sFlowTend now running in fullscreen." >> $log

echo >> $log

echo "Have fun!" >> $log
```

Edit root's crontab.

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Add the following line to the end of the `crontab`.

```
@reboot bash /sflowtrend.sh
```

Reboot, and try connecting to your server, port `6789`

```
http://ubuntu-hostname:6789
```

This worked for me, and I wanted to share.

Have fun!

---

*Sources*

- [Remote X applications on Headless Ubuntu Server](http://www.matt-barrett.com/2010/01/remote-x-on-headless-server/)
- [Arranging windows from the GNU/Linux command line with `wmctrl`](http://movingtofreedom.org/2010/08/10/arranging-windows-from-the-gnulinux-command-line-with-wmctrl/)
- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Comment: probably people want to look at this as well https://askubuntu.com/questions/47642/how-to-start-a-gui-software-on-a-remote-linux-pc-via-ssh