# Running a graphical application through ssh and keeping it alive

Tags: ssh, screen, gui, nohup

I want to run a GUI application from a remote client via ssh and keep it alive (and eventually reconnect to it) after the connection is closed.

As an example: I want, from my home pc, to open a graphical backup tool on the server and get it running. Then I disconnect from the server, shut down my pc, etc. Later, I reconnect to the server and reopen the GUI session to check on the backup progress.

I tried screen and nohup, after starting a session with ssh -X, but the process is killed as soon as I disconnect from the ssh server.

I also followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47642/how-to-start-a-a-gui-software-on-a-remote-linux-pc-via-ssh), but the application didn't open.

Then I tried screen with xpra, following the steps [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2026562&p=12106120#post12106120), but couldn't get the GUI application to show on my pc (no errors, just nothing happens on the last step, xpra attach)... the process is running on the server, however... I just can't see it. It might be important to note that it always outputs this when I open the program (tried firefox and google-chrome):

```
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":7".
```

On a side note, I know I can use VNC or something like that. But I want to do it the hard way, because I like suffering with Linux.

EDIT: I just figured out that xpra seems to be working. I ran xpra attach :7 on the server side and it opened the application Window. Problem seems to be on the remote connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by updating xpra, following the instructions [here](http://winswitch.org/downloads/debian-repository.html). I was using the Ubuntu 12.04 default xpra.