# DISPLAY command on the command line

Tags: 12.04, command-line, graphics, xorg, display

What does the command `export DISPLAY=:0`on terminal do ??

Is it possible to change the number from 0 to some other value..

Answer (score 1):

`DISPLAY=:0.0` is "the first configured screen"

`DISPLAY=:0.1` is "the second configured screen"

And the EXPORT actually sets the variable to that value. It is used to tell X server to show what is comming next on that display. Example: [How to start a GUI software on a remote Linux PC via SSH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47642/how-to-start-a-a-gui-software-on-a-remote-linux-pc-via-ssh)

And yes, technically it should be possible to run KDE on tty6 and Unity on tty7. I have done it before (as in 2010) but I saw a question a while back about how to set that up and I failed to find a correct answer on how to do this with Unity. It needs to be done with the LightDM config and I can find the setting to change the port it uses (so change tty7 to tty6) but have not seen how to use both at the same time.