# How to use Sublime Text editor over SSH?

Tags: ssh, sublime-text

First off, I'm new to SSH. I would like to use Sublime Text as my text editor on my computer. However, I cannot install it on the computers that I am connecting to with SSH. How can I use it as my text editor?

Comment: I believe Sublime Text is a GUI app, so you would not be able to use it over an SSH connection. You should have ever be able to install it, by adding the PPA (if needed) running sudo apt-get update and then sudo apt-get install "program name".

Comment: actually it is possible to run GUI apps using so-called X forwarding. I've done that, more or less works in local network. True hell when running between continents.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start a GUI software on a remote Linux PC via SSH](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47642/how-to-start-a-gui-software-on-a-remote-linux-pc-via-ssh)

Comment: Another way would be to mount the remote file system with sshfs and run the editor locally.

Comment: Tried [sshfs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sshfs)?

Answer (score 5):

One simple way is to mount your remote SSH server with your File Manager, which is **Nautilus** by default in Ubuntu.

To do so, open any directory (go to **Home** for example), and enter your remote server in **Address Bar** (press <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> to edit current location). Type-in desired address with this format:

```
sftp://username@server.example.com:22/home/username
```

After login, your remote server should be mounted like local media - check left Side Bar for it (<kbd>F9</kbd> to hide/show SideBar). You can **Bookmark** in Nautilus your remote location with <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>.

You can open files and Sublime Text's projects this way.