# How to start X application from SSH

Tags: command-line, xorg, ssh, gui, telnet

I've tried to search this topic in google, but without any significant results.

I need to start some GUI app from terminal, but I don't care what this app is showing me. In addition, I need to start few instances of this application in different sessions. It's connected with some GUI automated tests, so I know what I want and I'm looking for an answer :).

I think the proper steps should be:

1. Init new X window session
2. Get my new session id
3. export it to env variable (export DISPLAY:13.0)
4. run my app

but I'm stuck at first step. does anybody here had similar problem?

--- EDIT:
1) I don't care about GUI output - i need only stdout and stderr from my app. - that's why this question is not duplicate - know google well :) . I don't want to redirect output to my own GUI.

Comment: I think you can just start an X and then run it.

Comment: It's not clear. Do you have a graphic desktop running locally? Or do you want to run an X application with no real display, neither locally nor remotely?

Comment: Look at http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-X-Apps.html --- maybe it can help.

Comment: Rmano: I need to run app and click into it with robot-framework + selenium library - but I don't need to see any output from GUI, just logs from my scripts - is it an answer for your question?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you don't care to see what the application is doing, you can supply it with a "virtual" x server with xvfb:

> Xvfb provides an X server that can run on machines with no display
>   hardware  and no physical input devices. It emulates a dumb
>   framebuffer using virtual  memory. The primary use of this server was
>   intended to be server testing,  but other novel uses for it have been
>   found, including testing clients  against unusual depths and screen
>   configurations, doing batch processing with  Xvfb as a background
>   rendering engine, load testing, as an aid to porting the  X server to
>   a new platform, and providing an unobtrusive way to run  applications
>   that don't really need an X server but insist on having one  anyway.

After installing it, you can start it with:

```
sudo Xvfb :10 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
```

it'll run in the background, then you start your clients with:

```
DISPLAY=:10 your-client
```

Comment: There is also nice script provided with Xvfb - xvfb-run which is doing exactly this thing which I need: create virtual display and execute command passed as argument.

Answer (score 19):

A short command:

```
ssh -X <username>@<host> gedit &
```

from `man ssh`

```
-X      Enables X11 forwarding.
        This can also be specified on a per-host basis in a configuration file.

        X11 forwarding should be enabled with caution.  Users with the
        ability to bypass file permissions on the remote host (for the
        user's X authorization database) can access the local X11
        display through the forwarded connection. An attacker may then
        be able to perform activities such as keystroke monitoring.
```

---

1. Check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server side:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
   ```

   for the lines below:

   ```
   X11Forwarding yes
   X11UseLocalhost no
   ```

   Restart the ssh srever, if you have made changes:

   ```
   sudo service ssh restart
   ```
2. Check `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on the client side:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/ssh/ssh_config
   ```

   for the lines below

   ```
   ForwardX11 yes
   ForwardX11Trusted yes
   ```

Comment: `ssh -Y <username>@<host>` is what I prefer. https://superuser.com/a/123816

Comment: @rehctawrats You can also use compression: `ssh -CY <username>@<host>` but I haven't tried this out yet.

Answer (score 12):

You just need to run export DISPLAY=:id# in your ssh session and programs run will run on the remote display. A quick example:

```
maythux@maythuxPC:~$ ssh testSSH@myServer
maythux@maythuxPC:~$ export DISPLAY=:0
maythux@maythuxPC:~$ gedit
```

Now `gedit` will run on the user named testSSH display

You can shorten this all down into single command:

```
ssh testSSH@myServer "DISPLAY=:0 nohup gedit"
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me. [This](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11650317/) is what I get.

Comment: If the remote myServer is running X, the default `DISPLAY` is `:0`, not `:1`. It will only work if the user you connect to (`testSSH`) is the same one that is running the remote X server, otherwise auth tricks are needed.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display about the auth tricks.

Comment: @Rmano It was just example and not real value, The OP must put the correct number

Comment: You need `ssh -Y` or `ssh -X`. Exporting the display won't be enough.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47642/how-to-start-a-gui-software-on-a-remote-linux-pc-via-ssh

Comment: perfect, thanks! to not block current session waiting to command return, add `&` after the command. To run a command in a remote Raspberry I used `lxterminal --working-directory=path-to-serverjs -e node server.js`. It opened Node in a new terminal on remote desktop. Eureka! Kisses.

Comment: command prompt is `maythux@maythuxPC`, even when on `testSSH@myServer`?