# How can I set up a 2nd computer to run apps remotely via GUI?

Tags: 14.04, remote

I usually have many programs open, and my memory use is at 95%. That presents some problems.

Would like to know if it's possible to setup another computer on the same network and run some apps there (Chrome or LibreOffice, for example) but operate them from this machine screen,keyboard, mouse. Is that what X-windows is for?

My machine runs 14.04LTS on a i7-4770 with 16GB (motherboard ram limit).

I'd prefer to have each app in its own window, instead of all the remote apps inside a VNC window.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup x11vnc to access with graphical login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229989/how-to-setup-x11vnc-to-access-with-graphical-login-screen)

Comment: Also see the second answer to this [question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633782/how-to-start-x-application-from-ssh)