# Ubuntu opening program via ssh leads non-interactive window and libGL error

Tags: drivers, nvidia, ssh, opengl

I am connected through ssh to an Ubuntu 18.04 where I manually installed Cuda 11.1 and nvidia-driver-455. From my host machine (macOS) I open the terminal, start the ssh session, and run `ncu-ui` to open the Nvidia Nsight Compute. The program opens on my host machine, but I cannot click on it and the terminal shows the following error:

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I get the following In case case, it looks like the problem is general and not strictly related to this particular software. I tried different solution online, but none worked for me.

A few more details.

Running `LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose ncu-ui`:

```
libGL: MESA-LOADER: dlopen(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so)
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/ubuntu/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/ubuntu/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Running `sudo ldconfig -p | grep -i gl.so`:

```
    libwayland-egl.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1
    libwayland-egl.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so
    libQt5OpenGL.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5
    libQt5OpenGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so
    libOpenGL.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so.0
    libOpenGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so
    libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
    libGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
    libEGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so.1
    libEGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so
```

Running `sudo find / -name libGL.so.1`:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/opt/nvidia/nsight-systems/2020.3.4/host-linux-x64/Mesa/libGL.so.1
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/58a078699aab58f5c79a9ae10cc1e6535ddf6a8804da85cb53fb357e11aee1f4/merged/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/13ee7966eb1a1dec6fc73393791f85321aded603f5badb226ac2fa8f3d3de8e9/diff/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
```

Running `nvcc --version`:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Oct_12_20:09:46_PDT_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.1, V11.1.105
Build cuda_11.1.TC455_06.29190527_0
```

Running `nvidia-smi`:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 455.45.01    Driver Version: 455.45.01    CUDA Version: 11.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   44C    P8    10W /  70W |      0MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How can I solve?

Note: I need to keep the exact same nvidia driver and cuda versions

Comment: I don't understand. Are you trying to open a graphical interface in a ssh session?

Comment: Yeah, I think it uses X11. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/47642/how-to-start-a-gui-software-on-a-remote-linux-pc-via-ssh

Comment: I'd look [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/886398/906933)

Comment: Yeah that's what I am doing. But I have the error above ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't probably related to drivers but to XQuartz on my Mac.

Running this on my Mac makes the XQuartz window clickable:

```
defaults write org.x.x11 wm_click_through -bool true
```

Source: http://exoplanets.astro.yale.edu/tutorials/macos/mouse_clicks.php

Also, not sure it is related, but I installed gnome and vnc. So if you have the same issue, try the following commands. I really don't think you'll need vnc, but for sake of completeness, since I haven't tried, I'll write all the commands I run on my Mac:

```
sudo apt install -y xserver-xorg-core
sudo apt install -y tigervnc-standalone-server tigervnc-xorg-extension tigervnc-viewer
sudo apt install -y ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```