# unable to launch virtualbox using SSH (Qt FATAL: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized)

Tags: apt, upgrade, ssh, virtualbox, qt

I have a Home Assistant virtual machine in Virtual Box. I typically access it using GUI, but  now i'm using the device in a headless setup, so i'm trying to open it using ssh access.

The issue I encountered while opening virtualbox (`$ virtualbox`) with a headless setup:

> Qt FATAL: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

> Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

> Aborted (core dumped)

I have tried `$ sudo purge virtualbox` and `$ sudo install virtualbox` to reinstall the program.

It didn't help.

I reinstalled oracle extension pack using `$ sudo apt install virtualbox-ext-pack` and using `$ sudo modprobe vboxdrvhere` to avoid configuration errors.

I also tried to update packages using `$ sudo apt update`.

And upgrading them using `$ sudo apt upgrade`, and also upgrading individual packages listed using `$ apt list --upgradable` and `$ sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade $PACKAGE` for remaining 28 packages.

I still can't open virtualbox using ssh.

Note: I'm quite new to all of this so I would greatly appreciate a more detailed answer for a newbie like me.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is solved by using command `DISPLAY=:0 nohup $PROGRAM` from this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/47658/1717825). Updating host device version and extension pack I think helped solve some other issues the device was having.