# Closing the terminal where "compiz --replace" is run, causes compiz to crash again

Tags: 11.04, compiz

So every once in a while compiz will crash, sometimes randomly, more often when I'm messing with the compiz settings.

I can restart compiz with `compiz --replace`, and it fixes the window decoration, etc., but that command never finishes in the terminal. If I close the terminal or ctrl-C, it causes compiz to crash all over. So the only thing I can do is just leave that terminal running (not a great solution).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the normal expected behaviour. If you hit CTRL+C compiz will stop. If you want to *detach* some command from the terminal (so it will not terminate with the terminal, and it will allow you to continue to use it) you can use nohup, like this:

```
nohup compiz --replace
```

There is much more info in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10547/how-to-clean-launch-a-gui-app-via-the-terminal-so-it-doesnt-wait-for-terminatio).

Comment: Personally, I just hit CTRL+ALT+F1, launch compiz in the console and keep it running in the foreground there, that way I can check the output.

Comment: That definitely answered my question, but as an aside, some compiz crashes so bad, the shortcut key to open a terminal is shot too. i know that I can open up a virtual terminal, and use DISPLAY=:0 compiz --replace, but this doest work with my dual monitors, it seems to reset things so everthing is on one monitor. you know the right command to make this work?

Comment: Sorry but no. I also use dual monitor (well the laptop lid and a external monitor) and compiz --replace keeps my settings (I'm still using both monitors, programs stay where they should) when I do it. The problem likely lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the Compiz Fusion Icon, which can easily be installed by dropping in a terminal the next:

```
sudo apt-get install fusion-icon
```

And after providing your password the fusion icon will be installed and a shortcut can be reached inside of the "System Tools" menu in the majority of the cases, if not, in a terminal drop the next:

```
fusion-icon
```

and in the Fusion Icon menu (right click), choose "Reload window manager" in order to force Compiz to reload, after which all your compiz features will get enabled and should not break after closing the Fusion Icon (even from Terminal).

[image]

Good Luck!

Comment: i will try this, but unfortunately, I dont think this will be a good solution, because when compiz crashes, it usually takes the system bar with it, so i wouldnt be able to restart from that button

Comment: Then you are experiencing a kind of major issue with something else, try using cairo-dock's compiz gadget or anything else that allow you gain access to these features, and try updating/upgrading your system/compiz, may I suggest to remove compiz and reinstall it? Your comments on this and your accepted answer leads to think something's wrong with your system... Please inform if you succeed...

Comment: i mainly noticed compiz crashes when i was changing settings, ever since making the main compiz changes, I haven't had to change much and i haven't been seeing crashes-

Answer (score 2):

You can use this as an alternative to nohup: `compiz --replace &`

Comment: what does the & do?

Comment: i tried this, didnt seem to change anything

Comment: **compiz --replace & disown** After doing this, you can hit ENTER and you should see a fresh prompt.