# How to open a file in it's own application like `start` in Windows and how to use `start .`?

Tags: command-line, windows, xorg

How to open a file in it's own application like `start` in Windows?

In Windows, at the command prompt, one could type `start .` and it would open a file browser for the current directory, or `start notepad` and it would open a new notepad Window.

How to do this in Ubuntu?

Note I am not referring to typing a specific program name like `pinta drawing.png`, but rather one-fits-all command instead, including one which can be used for file directories (that would be a good start)

Comment: `nautilus <file>`

Comment: Related to launching commands: [How to hide terminal output when executing a command?](https://askubuntu.com/q/98377/301745), [How to cleanly launch a GUI app via the Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/10547/301745)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

xdg-open (ref `man xdg-open`) is one way of doing it, and this can be aliased to for example the keyword `start` (which is otherwise not commonly used on Ubuntu):

Add the following to `~/.bash_aliases`;

```
alias start='xdg-open'
```

Logout/login from your current shell (or run the same manually), then try this;

```
start .
```

It will open current window in Nautilus file browser. God bless!

Comment: As xiota suggests, it might be both safer and easier to remember if the OP sets `alias openx='xdg-open' ` or something similar

Answer (score 4):

To run a program, just type its name directly.

```
lowriter
```

To open a document with the associated application, there are several options.

- `mimeopen` – This is easy for me to remember and doesn't require typing dashes.
- `kde-open` / `kde-open5` – First use is slow.
- `xdg-open` (as [Roel mentions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1149256/567307))

All of them open the default file manager when called to open a directory (including `.`).  There are likely others for different desktop environments (`gnome-open`).

I wouldn't alias "start" with any of these because it could cause confusion with `startx`. It would also overload the term "start", which conventionally refers to starting services, not opening files.