# How to open a GUI app from Terminal without losing terminal input

Tags: command-line, gui, x11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clean launch a GUI app via the Terminal (so it doesn't wait for termination)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10547/how-to-clean-launch-a-gui-app-via-the-terminal-so-it-doesnt-wait-for-terminati)

If I have a terminal open in X-window, I can start a GUI app from the terminal. If I give <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the GUI app closes and you get back the prompter in the terminal so you can write commands again.

For example: If I run `gedit`, it starts but it doesn't return control to that console so I cannot reuse it for other commands, If I want to regain control I need to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but that closes the GUI app. I need the GUI app to keep running but also to use further the console to start other apps or run other commands.

How to start a X-window app from terminal console, without leaving  that console occupied solely by that app?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply add `&` to your call to start it as [background process](http://www.astro.ku.dk/comp-phys/tutorials/background.shtml).

Example:

```
gedit sometext.txt &
```

Comment: cool, this one I didn't know :)

Comment: What is really cool about it, is that if you run the first `gedit`  in background `&` the subsequent `gedit` can be ran without the `&` if `gedit` is still open.

Comment: If you forgot to add the `&`, no problem. Just press Ctrl+z which will pause the program. Then enter `bg` which will let it continue in the background.

Answer (score 6):

I advise you to use gksudo if that app needs administrative access with the &

```
gksudo gedit sometext.txt &
```