# The meaning of ./ before a command

Tags: command-line

While I was executing a C program in terminal I wrote:

```
gcc -o demo demo.c
./demo
```

Actually my doubt is why we write `./` before `demo` and what does it mean?

Comment: How does this relate to Ubuntu?

Comment: It means "in the current directory". We do this so the operating system recognizes it is a file, not a command.

Answer (score 2):

When we execute any command in the terminal it is going to look for it in the PATH environment variable. By using ./ (relative path) we are telling the shell to look for that command in our current directory.

Check `echo $PATH`

There are two way to execute any commands

1. Putting its path in the PATH environment variable
2. Using the full path or a relative path to that programme (Ex. /opt/xyz/bin/someprogramme )

Answer (score 1):

> When bash interprets the command line, it looks for commands in
>   locations described in the variable $PATH. To see it type:
>
> ```
> echo $PATH
> ```
>
> Normally, he current directory is not in that list.
>   The reason for not having the current directory on that list is security.
>
> The `./` says: look in the current directory for my command rather than looking at all the directories specified in $PATH.

More about:

- [About the Use of Dot-Slash in Commands](http://www.linfo.org/dot_slash.html)
- [Why do you need ./ (dot-slash) before script name to run it in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6331075/2353900)
- [What is the meaning of ./ before a given path?](https://askubuntu.com/q/60277/147044)

Answer (score 0):

## You put "./" before every program you wish to execute.

Otherwise the terminal doesn't know what to do with "demo" file

Answer (score 0):

The "./" before a file name stand for "execute this file in th current directory" if the file that you want to execute is not in the same directory you are in you will need to specify the path o the file like this:

Xxxxx@xxxx /Documents/filetoexecute