# Where to install unpackaged applications?

Tags: software-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best place to install user apps?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148/what-is-the-best-place-to-install-user-apps)

I use Mac and Windows and I'm switching on Ubuntu. I use a opensource program that is not packaged, it is distributed as an archive. The Documentation indicates to add the executable in the "home" folder.

The app works regardless of the location, so where should I install an application in Ubuntu? What is the recommended or ideal location?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See for example this [question on installing applications](https://askubuntu.com/q/2053/17789). Basically /opt/ or /usr/local/ are good places. See the [Filesystem Hierachrchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES) for details.